# Should I "update to recommended settings" for Pods.xcproj, Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am running Cocoapods 1.3.1. I get a `Update to recommended settings` warning in Xcode 9. Should I update the project settings or will a future version of Cocoapods (eg 1.3.2) fix these warnings for me?

Comment: They will fix it.  It's annoying, but wait.

Answer (score 4):

It is a work in progress right now. You can see the current progress [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6863).

In the future, you can search for that in their Github Issues. These types of issues are usually tracked and fixed there.